# Finding integers in a file

Tags: python, file, loops

I need to find integers of a file. I need to get the average of these ints (I already have this part figured out). I get the error: "error on input []: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly"

EDIT - Code is working. Thank you everyone! DiCaprio helped me to come up with final solution.

I edited my final code to be this:

```
   def average_ints():
        integers = []
        num_ints = 0
        avg = 0
        with open("file") as f:
            for line in f:
                for i in line.split(' '):
                     integers.append(int(i))
                    num_ints = num_ints + 1
        avg = (sum(integers))/((num_ints))
        return avg
```

How can I find the integers of this file?

Comment: `int` is a built-in, never use that name for your objects

Comment: you probably should provide a sample of your file and full error message

Comment: Are the integers in the file associate.txt all on one line or is it one integer per line?

Comment: I'm confused by "if int in line:" do you mean to check if the line in the file is an integer? If so please look at the .is_integer() extension method;
https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#float.is_integer

Comment: @AzatIbrakov I don't have access to the file. The numbers are all one per line.  The program runs my function through multiple files names "associate.txt" to see if it is correct  - I don't have access to the file.

Comment: You mean the file is generated?

Comment: @BobbyDurrett It is one integer per line.

Comment: @MadisonCourto Yes.

Comment: "find integers of a file" is very misleading.. or at least could mean one of many things... i recommend rewording the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use cast `int(x)` to transform str to int. By default everything is read from file as str.

```
def average_ints():
    integers = 0
    num_ints = 0
    avg = 0
    with open("associate.txt") as f:
        for line in f:
            for i in line:
                # if i in line: <- this should always be True
                integers += int(i)  # + integers <- += adds and stores
                num_ints = num_ints + 1
    avg = integers/num_ints
    return avg
```

EDIT:

I just thought you probably get a problem with the `for i in line:` part.
Line would need to be split. try using `for i in line.split(' ')` assuming your ints are split by a space.

EDIT 2:

If it is one int per line use:

```
def average_ints():
    integers = 0
    num_ints = 0
    avg = 0
    with open("associate.txt") as f:
        for line in f:
            integers += int(line)
            num_ints = num_ints + 1
    avg = integers/num_ints
    return avg
```

Comment: To extend on this I think you should be checking that the input is an int before attempting to cast it.

Comment: @MadisonCourto: or use EAFP and catch `ValueError` exception

Comment: @AzatIbrakov agreed.

Comment: I understand that I need the line.split(' ') part, but I don't understand why. What purpose does it have in the function? @DiCaprio

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that 'int' in lines is a string, and you need to convert it to an integer first. You can do this by replacing 'int' with int(int).

This is assuming that there are only numbers (characters that can be represented as floats or integers) in the file. If not, you need to account for that.

It's also not a good idea to name a variable after a built-in function, so I would change the name int to something else.

Answer (score 0):

You probably shouldn't use "int" as variable as it's a built in and if you try to reference it later you wont be able to.

So by the looks of it you want to take all integers in a file and average them? Here's a function that will do it:

```
def avg_ints(x): # Where x is a file
    total = 0
    count = 0
    lines = x.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        for character in line:
            try:
                character = int(character)
                count += 1
                total += character
            except ValueError:
                pass
    return total/count
f = open("associate.txt")
print(avg_ints(f))
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using regular expressions?  It might work a little easier for you.

Read the file and using an expression like this should parse the file for integers.

```
[0-9]+
```

https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Or why not this, a straightforward solution:

```
def average_ints():
   with open("associate.txt") as f:
       integers=int(f.read())
       num_ints=len(str(integers))
   avg = integers/num_ints
   return avg
```

Just directly convert to integers without going trough each character

And if there are non-numeric values:

```
def average_ints():
   num_ints=0
   integers=0
   with open("associate.txt") as f:
       for i in f.read():
           if i.isdigit():
               num_ints+=1
               integers+=int(i)
   avg = integers/num_ints
   return avg
```

Comment: This is giving me the incorrect return value. Returned:3.8571429. Exepcted: 9.0

Comment: @ncohen10 Sorry, then i have no clue

Answer (score 0):

Another solution with try and except:

```
def average_ints():
    integers = 0
    num_ints = 0
    avg = 0
    with open("associate.txt") as f:
        for line in f:
            for s in line.split():
                try:
                    i = int(s)
                    integers = i + integers
                    num_ints = num_ints + 1
                except ValueError:
                    continue
    avg = integers/num_ints
    return avg
```

Comment: The comments say it is one integer per line so this is probably overkill.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily solve it using the regular expressions module.

```
import re

def avarage_ints():
    with open("associate.txt") as f:
        content = f.read()
    list_of_integer_strings = re.findall(r'\d+', content)
    list_of_integers = list(map(int, list_of_integer_strings))
    avg = sum(list_of_integers) / len(list_of_integers)
    return avg
```

That regular expression will match any string consisting of decimal numbers in the file's content and findall will return a list containing them.

You might want to avoid matching integers that are in a word. For example, not counting the '2' in "sample2". In that case, you could change the regular expression from `r'\d+'` 
to `r'\A\d+\s|\s\d+\s|\s\d+$'`

Answer (score 0):

I offer a slimmed down version of DiCaprio's answer with a few modifications to make sure you're just collecting integers and can use the function for multiple files.

```
def average_ints(path):
    integers = []
    with open(path) as f:
        for line in f:
            for i in line:
                if i.isdigit(): # Checks if string i represents an integer
                    integers.append(int(i)) # Appends the string as an integer to your list
    return sum(integers) / len(integers) # Calculates the average of the list items

print(average_ints('associate.txt')) # Your specific use case
```